# How do I print a .txt file line-by-line?

Tags: python, txt

I am making my first game and want to create a score board within a .txt file, however when I try and print the score board it doesn't work.

```
with open("Scores.txt", "r") as scores:
        for i in range(len(score.readlines())):
          print(score.readlines(i + 1))
```

Instead of printing each line of the .txt file as I expected it to instead it just prints []

The contents of the .txt file are:

> NAME:    AGE:    GENDER:    SCORE:

I know it's only one line but it should still work shouldn't it?

*Note there are spaces between each word in the .txt file, though Stack Overflow formatting doesn't allow me to show that.

Comment: cat Scores.txt to show what is in the txt file. and give an example  what you want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of `score.readlines()` to a variable. Then you can loop through it and index it.

```
with open("Scores.txt", "r") as scores:
    scorelines = scores.readlines()

for line in scorelines:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.readlines()` reads everything until it reaches the end of the file. Calling it repeatedly will return `[]` as the file seeker is already at the end.

Try iterating over the file like so:

```
with open("Scores.txt", "r") as scores:
    for line in scores:
        print(line.rstrip())
```